# Need to double press to release focus on Text Input from within a Modal with KeyboardAvoidingView

Tags: react-native, textinput

I have a Modal wrapping a KeyboardAvoidingView wrapping a few animated components. One of them is a TextInput and the other is a Button. When clicking on the button, keyboard is first hidden, and then need to click once again to reach the buttons "onPress"

Looked into the solution of wrapping the components with a scroll view and using a the prop keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'always'} but that doesn't work.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.paddingInput = new Animated.Value(0);
    this.state = {
        modalVisible: false,
        otherTip: '',
    }
}

  renderHoveringNote = () => {
    const {total, currentTipPercent} = this.props.rootStore.orderStore;
    return (
        <View>
            <KeyboardAvoidingView style={{flex: 1}}>
                <Animated.View style={{
                    marginBottom: this.paddingInput,
                    flex: 1
                }}>
                    <View>
                        <Text>Enter custom amount</Text>
                    </View>
                    <TextInput                  
                        onChangeText={value => {
                            this.setState({otherTip: value})
                        }}
                        autoFocus
                        value={this.state.otherTip}
                    />
                     <Button title='Save'
                      onPress={()=>{
                            ...do some stuff here
                            this.setState({modalVisible: false});
                            Keyboard.dismiss();
                 }}
                </Animated.View>

            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        </View>
    )
};


  renderOtherTipModal = () => {
    return (
        <Modal
            isVisible={this.state.modalVisible}
           onBackdropPress{()=>this.setState({modalVisible:false})}
            style={{margin: 0, flex: 1}}
            hideModalContentWhileAnimating={true}
        >
            {this.renderHoveringNote()}
        </Modal>
    )
};
```

One click should reach the onPress of the button

Comment: Try to use `keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"` for `KeyboardAvoidingView `

Comment: Maneesh - doesn't work.

Comment: Yahav - Try to set `Scrollview` as a parent to `Modal` and add `keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"` to `Scrollview`.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out - I had a few Scroll Views as parents to the Modal. It is important to have ALL of the parent Scroll Views to have keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'always'}.
After adding that, it worked great.